# React ref, When multiple refs are used, all children components are rerendered

Tags: reactjs, ref, rerender

I'm making a page that modifies values in db.

When the screen is initially rendered, receive a value from the server and put the value in the  tag.

like this
[rendered first page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g58kq.png)

And when you click the addbutton, one row is deleted, and when you click the apply button,
only the modified values are sent to the server.

What I'm trying to do is click the add button, hit the apply button, and if the row is empty, I focus on that

First of all, the function works fine. but I wonder if it's normal for all the children under it to re-render

The red square is the part where all child components are re-rendered.

[It's the profiler when i hit the delete button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZToN.png)

`Table.js`

```
function Tables({}){
  const rows = useSelector( state =>state.phoneData.data.rows);

  const refs = useMemo( ()=> new Array(rows.length).fill().map(()=>new Array(8).fill().map(()=>createRef())),[rows.length]);

  return(
      <StyledTable>
          <Row key={`top_row_head`} top />
          {rows.map( (row,i) =>
              <Row  ref={refs[i]} key={`row_body_${row.id}`} rowId={row.id}/>
          )}
      </StyledTable>
  );
}
```

`Row.js`

```
const Row = forwardRef(({top, rowId,children},ref) =>{
    console.log("row");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleDeleteButton = useCallback( (id) => {
            dispatch(phoneDataUpdate.Delete(id));
    },[]);

    if( top ) return(
        <StyledRow>
            <DeleteButton top/>
            {columns.map((column)=>
                <Column  key={`head_${column.name}`} width={column.width} top>
                    {column.name}
                </Column>
            )}
        </StyledRow>

    );
    return( 
        <StyledRow >
            <DeleteButton onClick={()=>handleDeleteButton(rowId)}> delete </DeleteButton>
            {columns.map((column, index)=>
                <Column key={`row_${rowId}_${column.name}`} width={column.width} textalign={column.textalign}>
                    <Input ref={ref[index]} colIndex={index} id={rowId} column={column} />
                </Column>   
            )}
        </StyledRow>
    );
});
```

`Reducer.js`

```
const PHONE_DATA = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA';
const PHONE_DATA_LOADING = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_LOADING';
const PHONE_DATA_SUCCESS = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_SUCCESS';
const PHONE_DATA_ERROR = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_ERROR';
const PHONE_DATA_ADD = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_ADD';
const PHONE_DATA_DELETE = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_DELETE';
const PHONE_DATA_CHANGE = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_CHANGE';
const PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_CHANGE = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_CHANGE';
const PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_DELETE = 'phoneData/PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_DELETE';

const dataInitRow = {
    id:null,
    model_name:null,
    machine_name:null,
    shipping_price:null,
    maker:null,
    created:null,
    battery:null,
    screen_size:null,
    storage:null,
};

const dataInit = {
    lastId:null,
    rows:[],
}

const initialState = {
    state:{
        loading:false,
        error:false,
    },
    data:dataInit,
    // refData:[],
    firstData:dataInit,
    dataChangeList:{
        dataAddList:[],
        dataDeleteList:[],
        dataUpdateList:[],
    },
};



// get Data From Server promisethunk
const phoneDataFetchAsync = createPromiseThunk(PHONE_DATA, restAPI.getAllPhoneInfo);

const phoneDataUpdate =({
    Add:()=>({
        type:PHONE_DATA_ADD,
    }),
    Delete:(id)=>({
        type:PHONE_DATA_DELETE,
        id: id,
    }),
    Change:(id, colName, value)=>({
        type:PHONE_DATA_CHANGE,
        id: id,
        colName:colName,
        value: value,
    }),
});
// const phoneDataAddRef=(length) =>({
//     type:PHONE_DATA_ADD_REF,
//     length,
// });

const phoneDataUpdateList = ({
    Change:(id,colName, value) => ({
        type:PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_CHANGE,
        id: id,
        colName: colName,
        value: value,
    }),
    Delete:(id, colName) => ({
        type:PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_DELETE,
        id: id,
    }),
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

export default function phoneData(state = initialState, action){
    // console.log(`add: ${state.dataChangeList.dataAddList}, delete: ${state.dataChangeList.dataDeleteList}, change: ${state.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList}`);
    switch(action.type){
        case PHONE_DATA_LOADING:
        case PHONE_DATA_SUCCESS:
        case PHONE_DATA_ERROR:
            return handleAsyncActions(PHONE_DATA)(state,action);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        case PHONE_DATA_ADD:
            return{
                ...state,
                data:{
                    ...state.data,
                    lastId: state.data.lastId +1,
                    rows: state.data.rows.concat({
                        ...dataInitRow,
                        id: state.data.lastId +1,
                    }),
                },
                dataChangeList:{
                    ...state.dataChangeList,
                    dataAddList: state.dataChangeList.dataAddList.concat( state.data.lastId +1),
                }
            };
        case PHONE_DATA_DELETE:
            const dataAddListIdx = state.dataChangeList.dataAddList.findIndex( val => val === action.id);
            console.log("deleteRow",action);
            return{
                ...state,
                // refData:state.refData.filter(row => row.id !== action.id),
                data:{
                    ...state.data,
                    rows:state.data.rows.filter(row => row.id !== action.id),
                },
                dataChangeList:{
                    ...state.dataChangeList,
                    
                    dataAddList: dataAddListIdx === -1
                                 ? state.dataChangeList.dataAddList
                                 : state.dataChangeList.dataAddList.filter(id => id !== action.id),
                    
                    dataDeleteList: dataAddListIdx === -1
                                 ? state.dataChangeList.dataDeleteList.concat(action.id)
                                 : state.dataChangeList.dataDeleteList,
                    },
            };
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        case PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_CHANGE:
            return produce(state, draft =>{
                const idx = state.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList.findIndex( row => row.id === action.id);

                if( idx === -1 ){
                    let initRow = {};
                    initRow.id = action.id;
                    initRow[action.colName] = action.value;
                    draft.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList.push(initRow);

                }else if( action.value !== state.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList[idx][action.colName]){
                    draft.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList[idx][action.colName] = action.value;
                }

            });
        case PHONE_DATA_UPDATE_LIST_DELETE:
            return produce(state,draft=>{
                const idx = state.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList.findIndex( row => row.id === action.id);
                if( idx !== -1){
                    if( Object.keys(draft.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList[idx]).length <= 1  ){
                        draft.dataChangeList.dataUpdateList.splice(idx,1);
                    }
                }
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}




export {phoneDataFetchAsync,
        phoneDataUpdate,
        phoneDataUpdateList,
        };
```

Comment: Can you share your reducer?

Comment: Yes, I just added a reducer to the body

Comment: Yes its expected that all rows rerender. You are updating the rows and you are using the selector to access those. So if they change, the useSelector renders the table and all its children. You would wrap the rows in React.memo to prevent renders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,So I export the row component to "export default React.memo(row);" But nevertheless, it still re-renders

Comment: Which means that some of the props are changing. And your refs do. You are creating new refs on every render, since you are missing the dependcy array in the useMemo.

Comment: Thank you so much I know the correct usage of useMemo

Comment: @Dorjd can you elaborate on what you use refs for. An alternative solution which doesn't involve changing refs and work

Comment: @Shubham Khatri I use ref to focus the input tag
And I changed export React.memo(Row) to
export default React.memo(Row, 
    (prev,next)=>{
        return prev.itemsRef  !== next.itemsRef
    });
last,without don't use forwardRef in Row, passing ref with props